# error en el metodo len cuando inicio con 0 en python

Tags: python

No comprendo porqué falla el metodo len en este caso

```
while True: 
  clave = int(input("INTRODUCE TU CLAVE PERSONAL DE 4 DIGITOS: "))
  clave_en_letras = str(clave)
  if len(clave_en_letras) != 4 :
    print("LA CLAVE SOLO PUEDE TENER 4 DIGITOS.")
    continue
  elif len(clave_en_letras) == 4:
    print("Bienvenido")
   break
```

SI INTRODUZCO UNA CLAVE QUE EMPIECE CON 0, CUALQUIERA SEA ESTA, Y TIENE 4 DIGITOS, EL METODO LEN LO INTERPRETA COMO SI EL 0 NO EXISTIERA.
POR EJEMPLO, LA CLAVE 0549 o 0111 las interpreta como si fueran 3 digitos en lugar de 4.
EN CAMBIO, SI INTRODUZCO 01111 ahí si acepta que se cumple la condición del while y termina el codigo con el mensaje de BIENVENIDO.

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que acepte a ese caracter 0 como un numero valido.

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto `input("INTRODUCE TU CLAVE PERSONAL DE 4 DIGITOS: ")` ya retorna un valor tipo `str`. Si no ingresas ningún caracter es equivalente a introducir `''` una cadena vacía. cuando intentas convertir eso a un número falla porque `''` no se puede convertir a ningún número.

Lo más sencillo es poner un condicional `if`:

```py
while True: 
    clave_en_letras = input("INTRODUCE TU CLAVE PERSONAL DE 4 DIGITOS: ")
    if clave_en_letras=='':
        clave = 0
    else:
        clave = int(clave_en_letras)
    if len(clave_en_letras) != 4 :
        print("LA CLAVE SOLO PUEDE TENER 4 DIGITOS.")
        continue
    elif len(clave_en_letras) == 4:
        print("Bienvenido")
    break
```

Hay una forma menos intuitiva pero más corta usando `or`:

```py
while True: 
    clave_en_letras = input("INTRODUCE TU CLAVE PERSONAL DE 4 DIGITOS: ") or "0"
    clave = int(clave_en_letras) 
    if len(clave_en_letras) != 4 :
        print("LA CLAVE SOLO PUEDE TENER 4 DIGITOS.")
        continue
    elif len(clave_en_letras) == 4:
        print("Bienvenido")
    break
```

La cual evalúa primero lo que has ingresado en `input` y si es equivalente a `False` va a asginar el siguiente valor después de `or`

Answer (score 0):

Esto ocurre porque realizas primero la conversión de string a int al ingresar `clave` y se eliminan los 0 antes de obtener `clave_en_letras`, solo debes cambiar el orden de declaracion de variables.

```
clave_en_letras = input("INTRODUCE TU CLAVE PERSONAL DE 4 DIGITOS: ")
clave = int(clave_en_letras)
```